# How to count the number of elements accessed in a list?

Tags: list

Suppose that we have made *kn* total accesses to the elements in a list *L* of *n* elements, for some integer *k >= 1*. What are the minimum and maximum number of elements that have been accessed fewer than *k* times?

Comment: Minimum: 0. Maximum: n-1. This also doesn't seem like a programming problem, but rather a mathematical problem.

Comment: Seems like a counting problem.

Comment: @immibis thank you so much! I know, but it's for my CompSci course at college so I thought this is the right place to ask it! Would you mind explaining it please? I'm so sorry, I'm new to all this! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

It is a mathematical problem, but I'll try to explain.

For the minimum:
Imagine that for every n number of times the list is accessed, every individual element is accessed. Then doing that k times will make sure every element is accessed k times. Minimum = 0.

For the maximum:
Just imagine that only one element is accessed every single time. Then 1 element is visited kn times and the rest 0. Maximum = n-1.

Hope that helps!